# downloading a text file in r

Tags: r, file, text, download

Ok, so this is really silly. Why am I getting this error? Cant R just create a new file in the working directory?

Many thanks

```
> url <- "http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/lubos.pastor/research/liq_data_1962_2013.txt"
> download.file(url, file, mode='wb')
Error in download.file(url, file, mode = "wb") : 
  invalid 'destfile' argument
```

Comment: What is "file", knowing that `file` is a base function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## To download in working directory with destination file.txt:

```
getwd()
url <- "http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/lubos.pastor/research/liq_data_1962_2013.txt"
download.file(url, "file.txt" )
```